# What is meant by "weakly dependent" on p. 64 of Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, graphical-model

I'm reading Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning ([here](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.Online) is a free online copy).

On page 64, beginning with equation (4.2.20), Barber says

> Our aim is
>   to show that a distribution of the form [below] cannot satisfy the
>   Markov property $x_1 \perp\!\!\!\perp x_3 | x_2, x_4$
>
> $$
> p(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \phi_{12}(x_1, x_2) \phi_{23}(x_2, x_3)
> \phi_{34}(x_3, x_4) \phi_{41}(x_4, x_1) \phi_{13}(x_1, x_3)
> $$

Later, in equation (4.2.23):

> If we assume that the potential $\phi_{13}$ is weakly dependent on
>   $x_1$ and $x_3$,
>
> $$
> \phi_{13}(x_1, x_3) = 1 + \epsilon\psi(x_1, x_3)
> $$

What does "weakly dependent" mean exactly in this context? And further, what object does the symbol $\psi$ represent?